# Minor issue when sharing custom document

Tags: google-drive-api

I've integrated the Google Drive share dialog and it works like a charm.
The only minor issue that I came across is that the notification email contains a broken icon.
It would be ideal if the proper icon for my custom mimetype (as configured in the Google API Console) would be used.

This is how the notification mail looks like:

[image]

Comment: I'm about to implement sharing. If it's not too cheeky to ask, could you post the code you're using :-)

Comment: Check out this code snippet:
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#launching_the_google_drive_sharing_dialog_in_your_app